# transforming RPC API to Rest API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am started playing with REST, and trying to understand how I can map following RPC style Web Method to REST style.

```
public PerformanceResponse GetPerformance(int lineId, int maxNumberOfEntries, bool ascending)
```

This is the only operation I have related to Performance and it just extracts some information from DB.

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: What is a line? If a line is a fundamental part of your application and performance is one property (out of many) that a line has, it should probably be `yourapi.com/lines/lineId/performance/ascending/maxNumber`

Comment: @japreiss lineId is something unique in my application , PerformanceResponse is a complex datastructure

Comment: OK... but is a line a fundamental unit of your application?  Like - in Stack Overflow, a User is a fundamental unit whereas a Reputation Value isn't.  It's `Users/userID/reputation/` not `reputations/userID/`.

Comment: @japreiss , ok I agree with you . but how my routing will look like if I am doing yourapi.com/lines/lineId/performance/ascending/maxNumber I understand that I will have only get action in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would design the API:

- Create a PerformanceController
- Have a Get method with parameters you had
- Design URL to be `/Performance/{lineId}?maxNumberOfEntries={max}&ascending={asc}`

Answer (score 0):

Is

http://example.com/Performance/1/2/0

where 1 is lineID, 2 is maxNumber and 0 is ascending

an answer?
(your question is a bit vague - please specify)